# How to show the number of each post has been read in a while loop?

Tags: query-posts

I have this code in my **header.php** and it is working:

```
<div id="news">
        <?php query_posts('category_name=news'); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="new">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                </a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p>
                    <span class="autor">Author: <?php the_author(); ?></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <span class="autor">Date: <?php the_date(); ?></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;

                </p>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to do something like:

```
<span class="views">Views: <?php the_views(); ?></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

to show each post how many times was read. However, it is throwing an error. How to solve this?

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_views()

Comment: Is this not a build in function of WP?

Comment: Also, [don't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_views()` is not a built in function of WordPress. In fact, WordPress does not, by default, log the number of views of posts.

There are probably several plug-ins that exist which add this functionality. The only one I have ever used (and its one I've never had any problems with) is WP-Postviews http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/.

Answer (score 1):

in function.php
put this code

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count.' Views';}
function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}}
```

then in single.php 
put this code `<?php
          setPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>`

> 

to show views count put this code anywhere you want `<span class="views"><?php
          echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
?></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;`
that will count each visit to the post you can put it in the loop.php/index.php
to view each post views

Comment: Hi @Shady - this - at the core of it, is essentially what wp-postviews does. But you might always want to think about post revisions, the same user viewing the same post, whether to count a view by an admin, or by a bot and how to deal with Caching plug-ins etc.

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks for your advise, i know its not perfect solution for the viewing count, i just wanted to share the code if any one like me dosn't like dozens of plugins running on his WordPress site so its simple .